# notify admin on new order is not working

Tags: admin, email-translation

I have been try solve this by myself but need help now, notify admin on all new order is not working. When I check `var/log/exception` on my root file I find this error on it. Please someone tell me what to do?

```
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /home/melmatcb/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /home/melmatcb/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /home/melmatcb/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /home/melmatcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(241): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#4 /home/melmatcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/melmatcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
```

Comment: Do any of the other email triggers work? Ie, if you create an account do you receive the notification email?

Comment: yes, if i create account the email for account create is working but admin notification is not working

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.9.1 require cron set up, else the admin email queue will not be send.
To set up cron please see manual:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron

Cron in the backend can be found:

> System ->advanced->system->cron ->see the default settings ->save settings

I had the same problem as you. I just re-resaved default settings and got all new orders I ve been testing at once :) ...
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error sometimes when I tried to send an email with a mail-template that did not exist.

In the backend at `System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails`, check the template that is assigned to this e-mail. Is it the default template, and does the file exist in the filesystem in `app/locale/[your-locale]/email/`?
It is possible that the mail template was not delivered with the locale you configured in the backend.
If it is a custom template, check if it exists under `System -> Transactional Mails`.

Answer (score 0):

If create account mail is working, then there should be issue with mail queue. Ensure that cron is running.

You can install this module and check cron: www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html